# When selecting features which are duplicated it does not appear right in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a road network data. In this data, I have segments which has a twin segment in the opposite way in the **same layer**. It is being considered as a single carriageway. So their just start points and end points crosses (which will lead me to determine the direction). Thus I have two issues,

1. When I try to select one of them, its twin segment could not be seen clearly. For instance, the segment with id 3823233 can be seen clear and 38223228 cannot. See below images,

[image] [image]

2. Moreover, when I try to zoom out a little bit the selections just disappear. I think it is also because of the twin geometry issue.

I want to make the selected one appear on the top all the time. Any suggestions to deal with ? *(Note that I am going to use my own selection tool in a project. So, I am open to any PyQGIS solution.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have some luck playing with the feature rendering order, ordering by `is_selected()` (though it is not always straightforward...)

[image]

Alternatively, since the selection is only a color - and not a full style - is to change the size of the selected feature. It works well if all features have the same width.

Click the `epsilon` icon beside the `width`, select `edit` and enter the expression `if(is_selected(),1,0.26)`  (if the feature is selected, width is 1. Else, width is 0.26, the default).

The selected features remains under other ones, but now you can see them.

[image]

And of course you use both options together (bigger and on top)

Comment: Thanks ! they both worked for me. I am going to use the both methods combined. But, I am having really tough times with the second issue which is after zoom out or moving the canvas little further the selections just disappear. Do you know any method to solve that ?

Comment: @metecad I don't know, the selection should not be affected by panning/zooming