# Using v.distance to classify points far from overlapping polygons always return the same set of polygons

Tags: grass-gis, vector, distance

I have two vector layers with the distribution of an animal species. EDIT: I'm showing how the maps look in QGIS, but I'm working in GRASS GIS. First dataset:

[image: First dataset]

Second dataset:

[image: Second dataset]

As you can see, these two datasets have been produced by different authorities and therefore some geometries are repeated (for instance, Corse Island). If I merge these two datasets the final vector map, therefore, looks like this:

[image: Final map]

One of them (in this case, the first one) has a column (`x_CommonName`) which is filled, while in the other the column is empty. The attribute table looks like this:

[image: Attribute table]

Moreover, if I try to select Corse Island from the first dataset, it doesn't get selected:

[image]

Whereas it does from the second:

[image]

All of this is because I have a shapefile of points and I want to know how far a point is from a polygon, if a point is inside my polygons, and from which of the two datasets (the first or the second). I first add 3 new columns to my shapefile of points (`points`): one with the distance of the point from the polygon (`dist`), one that tells if it's inside the polygon or not (`area`), and the last one which tells from which polygon (`areacat`). Then I calculate the distances and I upload the column `areacat`.

```
v.db.addcolumn map=points layer=1 columns='dist INT,area INT,areacat VARCHAR(250)' --o
v.distance --o from=points to=map from_layer=1 to_type=boundary,area upload=dist,dist column=dist,area
v.distance --o from=points to=map upload=to_attr column=areacat to_column=x_CommonName
```

Usually, this works pretty well if there are no overlapping features (as in this case with Corse Island and other islands). However, in such cases, what is being recorded under `areacat` is always the second dataset. I was wondering 1) why, 2) if it is linked to the fact that I cannot select the geometries of the first dataset in the merged vector layer (`map`), and 3) if there's a way to avoid this behaviour.
I am using GRASS 7.8.6 on a server running Ubuntu 18.04.6 from a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Not sure to have understood what you were precisely trying to do here but if you want to select the geometries of the first dataset you should try using "Multipart to single part"

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried it but I get the same problem (i.e., Corse Island doesn't get "selected/highlighted" in the 1st dataset). But I don't really see how is this relevant for my aim (running v.distance in GRASS GIS) or for the question itself... I edited it specifying I'm using QGIS only to show the maps, the selection thing is just something I was wondering could have had an impact on the problem I found with v.distance.

Comment: The selected geometry doesn't appear selected because it is below another un-selected geometry. See this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377314/when-selecting-features-which-are-duplicated-it-does-not-appear-right-in-qgis/377371#377371) to change the rendering order.

Comment: If you ask to get "the" closest polygon, but there are two, which one should be recorded? A random one?... first found one? last found one? Since you don't specify any order, the returned polygon may change through time and shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: @JGH thanks for the answer! Yes, this is exactly my point. I was asking also how to avoid/change this behaviour (if possible).

Comment: Sorry, but your question/problem is still not clear. Are you trying to merge two polygon layers? Can you share the data? WHere are the points that you mention? In your `v.distance` command you have `to=map`. Do your really have a polygon layer named `map`?

Comment: Hi Micha, thanks for answering. No, I'm not trying to merge polygon layers: they are already merged, but they come from two different datasets. Therefore, some polygons overlap. But when this happens, when I try to assign to a point its distance from a polygon and if it's inside (or not) a polygon, and especially from which dataset this polygon comes from, the point gets assigned always to the same dataset (even if there are 2 datasets overlapping). I was wondering if there's a reason and if it possible to change it (like assigning the point randomly to dataset 1 or 2).

Comment: And no, the polygon layer it's not called "map", it was just an example. It's called, for instance, Eliomysquercinus. Here's the sample data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GHj4RxspePgj80klX4FLI_9Q_eGRjdcp?usp=sharing